# Dart SDK is not configured after flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter, dart

I have upgraded flutter as I am getting notification to upgrade it. After upgrading my project stopped working and I found that it is asking me to configure Dart. I failed to find my flutter folder which I configured a few months back.

Comment: If you are using windows, just check your system path variables to find the path to the flutter directory.

Comment: No its Mac and PATH is already there I just checked.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Is your IDE still pointing at a directory? Otherwise that might be the case?

Comment: I solved it by simply run flutter upgrade command again. May be there was some disconnect during upgrade so that was not finished.